# Database not connecting Tomcat,Servlet, MYSQL

Tags: java, html, mysql, tomcat, servlets

First Post

Hello everyone, I am trying to run a java web project that was developed by another developer. At this time I am trying to run that project but its not connected to database. In login screen I am retrieving some data from database and displaying them in dropdown list but when user enters name and password its not showing anything like error message or redirecting to next page nor showing any error in console.
This is my connection code:

```
public final class MySqlConnect {
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySqlConnect.class.getName());
public Connection conn;
private Statement statement;
public static MySqlConnect db;
private MySqlConnect() {

    String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
     String dbName = "anish";
     String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     String userName = "root";
     String password = "root";




    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        this.conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
    }
    catch (Exception sqle) {
        logger.info(sqle.getMessage());
    }
}

public static synchronized MySqlConnect getDbCon() {
    if ( db == null ) {
        db = new MySqlConnect();
    }
    return db;

}

public ResultSet query(String query) throws SQLException{
    statement = db.conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println(query);
    ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(query);
    return res;
}

public int insert(String insertQuery) throws SQLException {
    statement = db.conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println(insertQuery);
    int result = statement.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
    return result;

}

public int insertAndgeneratedRowId(String insertQuery) throws SQLException {
    statement = db.conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println(insertQuery);

    int result = statement.executeUpdate(insertQuery,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    int  auto_id = 0;
    if(result > 0) {
       ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
        rs.next();
        auto_id = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    return auto_id;

}
```

}

It seems that connection is OK because I am getting the dropdown's data, but 
when I do query for something then its not showing anything. 
e.g. After user entered name and password, it should redirect to next page.

This is the HTML file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta+Stencil">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/LoginPage.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loadLoginPageData()">
<div class="row">
  <div class="extra_column" style="background-color:#fff;">
<form action="LoginController" method="post">

    <h2> Get Started </h2>
    <label style="color:#8e44ad;margin-right:10px;"><b>SELECT ASSEMBLY: </b></label>
    <select id="slloginAssembly" name="Assembly">
    <option>Select Assembly</option>
  </select><br><br>

    <input type="text" class="inp" id="loginUserID" placeholder="Enter Userno." name="uname" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="v1" name="Verifiactiontype" onclick="chooseType(this.value)" value="password" checked> Password
    <input type="radio" id="v2" name="Verifiactiontype" onclick="chooseType(this.value)" value="OTP"> OTP<br><br>

    <input type="password" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
    <br><br>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" id="btnLogin" value="SIGN IN"  class="w3-button w3-green w3-round-xlarge">
    <input type="button" id="btnGenerate" value="VERIFY" class="w3-button w3-green w3-round-xlarge" style="display: none;" onclick="generateOTP()">
    </p>

    <!-- <span>Forgot<a href="#">password?</a></span> -->

</form>
</div>
  <div class="column" style="background:linear-gradient(220deg,  #9933ff, #a64dff);color:white">
    <h3>WELCOME TO</h3>
    <p style="text-align:center;"><img src="image/logo.PNG" alt="LOGO" style="width:244px;height:164px;"></p>
    <p style="margin-left: 2px;">Creating data driven solutions for</p>
    <p style="margin-left: -1px;">election campaigns</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>

     $('#v1').focus(function() {
        $("#loginPassword").attr('placeholder', 'Enter Password')
        $("#btnLogin").attr('value', 'SIGN IN')
        document.getElementById("btnLogin").setAttribute("type","submit");
    })

    $('#v2').focus(function() {
        $("#loginPassword").attr('placeholder', 'Enter OTP')
        $("#btnLogin").attr('value', 'Generate')




    })

    $('#btnLogin').click(function() {

        $("#btnLogin").attr('value', 'Verify')

    })

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

And this is Java file

```
 @WebServlet("/LoginController")
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName());

    AdminService adminServiceImpl ;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginController() {

        super();

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getParameter("caller").equals("generateOTP"))
        {
            String assembly=request.getParameter("AssemblyId");  
            String userid=request.getParameter("userId");  

            System.out.println(assembly+"  &  "+userid); 
            try {

                adminServiceImpl  = new AdminServiceImpl(); 
                adminServiceImpl.getGenerateOTP(assembly,userid); 
                response.getWriter().append("");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



            String assembly=request.getParameter("Assembly");  
            //String assembly=request.getParameter("LoginAssembly"); 
            String userid=request.getParameter("uname");  
            String logintype=request.getParameter("Verifiactiontype");  
            String password=request.getParameter("psw");  
            String otp=request.getParameter("LoginOTP");  


            adminServiceImpl  = new AdminServiceImpl();
            if(logintype.equalsIgnoreCase("password"))
            {
            LoginPojo loginPojo =   adminServiceImpl.validateWithPassword(assembly,userid,password);

                if(loginPojo.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
                    session.setAttribute("user", userid);
                    session.setAttribute("AssemblyID",assembly);
                    session.setAttribute("AssemblyName", loginPojo.getAssemblyName());
                    //session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30);

                    /* RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/MainPage.jsp");  
                        rd.forward(request,response); */
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.html");  
                    rd.forward(request,response); 
                }
                else {
                    // RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/LoginPage.html");  
                     RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
                        rd.forward(request,response);
                }




            }else if(logintype.equalsIgnoreCase("OTP")){
                if(adminServiceImpl.loginWithOTP(assembly,userid,password))
                {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
                    session.setAttribute("user", userid);
                    session.setAttribute("AssemblyID",assembly);
                    session.setAttribute("AssemblyName", "Udaipur");
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.html");  
                    rd.forward(request,response);
                }
                else {
                    // RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/LoginPage.html");
                     RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
                        rd.forward(request,response);
                } 
            }




          /*  if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){  
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");  
                rd.forward(request,response);  
            }  
            else{  
                out.print("Sorry username or password error");  
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
                rd.include(request,response);  
            }  */

    }

}
```

AdminServiceImpl.java

```
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AdminServiceImpl.class.getName());
CommonUtil commonUtil = new CommonUtil();
Properties properties;

public String CreateAssembly(String data) {

    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        String AssemblyName = (String) jsonObj.get("AssemblyName");

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        int i = con.insert("INSERT INTO `tbl_assembly` (`assembly_name`, `assembly_status`) VALUES ('"
                + AssemblyName + "', '1');");

        if (i > 0)
            return "success";
        else
            return "Failure";
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return null;
}

public JSONArray getAssembly() {
    JSONArray assemblyArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        ResultSet assemblyList = con.query("SELECT assembly_id, assembly_name,assembly_status FROM tbl_assembly ;");

        while (assemblyList.next()) {
            JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
            jO.put("AssemblyID", assemblyList.getInt(1));
            jO.put("AssemblyName", assemblyList.getString(2));
            jO.put("AssemblyStatus", assemblyList.getInt(3));
            assemblyArray.put(jO);
        }

        if (assemblyArray != null) {
            return assemblyArray;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }

    return new JSONArray();
}

public int toggleAssemblyStatus(String data) {
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        int recordId = (Integer) jsonObj.get("recordId"); 
        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();
        int i = con
                .insert("UPDATE `tbl_assembly` SET `assembly_status`=  case when assembly_status = 0 then 1 else 0 end WHERE `assembly_id`='"
                        + recordId + "'");
        int currentstatus = 0;
        if (i > 0) {
            ResultSet rs = con
                    .query("SELECT assembly_status FROM tbl_assembly WHERE `assembly_id`='" + recordId + "';");
            if (rs.next()) {
                currentstatus = rs.getInt(1);
            }

            return currentstatus;
        } else {
            return currentstatus;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return 0;
}

public JSONArray getPSAssembly() {
    JSONArray assemblyArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        ResultSet assemblyList = con
                .query("SELECT assembly_id, assembly_name FROM tbl_assembly where assembly_status = 1  ;");

        while (assemblyList.next()) {
            JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
            jO.put("AssemblyID", assemblyList.getInt(1));
            jO.put("AssemblyName", assemblyList.getString(2));

            assemblyArray.put(jO);
        }

        if (assemblyArray != null) {
            return assemblyArray;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }

    return new JSONArray();
}

public String CreatePS(String data) {
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        String AssemblyID = (String) jsonObj.get("AssemblyID");
        String PSName = (String) jsonObj.get("PolingStationName");

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        int i = con.insert("INSERT INTO `tbl_poling_stations` (`location_name`, `assembly_id`) VALUES ('" + PSName
                + "', '" + AssemblyID + "');");

        if (i > 0)
            return "success";
        else
            return "Failure";
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return null;
}

public JSONArray getPSList(String data) {
    JSONArray PSArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {

        jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        String AssemblyID = (String) jsonObj.get("AssemblyID");

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        ResultSet PSList = con.query(
                "SELECT location_id,location_name FROM tbl_poling_stations where assembly_id = " + AssemblyID);

        while (PSList.next()) {
            JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
            jO.put("PSID", PSList.getInt(1));
            jO.put("PSName", PSList.getString(2));

            PSArray.put(jO);
        }

        if (PSArray != null) {
            return PSArray;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }

    return new JSONArray();
}

public String CreateBooth(String data) {
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        String AssemblyID = (String) jsonObj.get("AssemblyID");
        String PolingStationID = (String) jsonObj.get("PolingStationID");
        String BoothName = (String) jsonObj.get("BoothName");

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        int i = con.insert("INSERT INTO `tbl_booth` (`booth_name`, `booth_status`, `polingstation_id`) VALUES ('"
                + BoothName + "', '1', '" + PolingStationID + "');");

        if (i > 0)
            return "success";
        else
            return "Failure";
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return null;
}

public JSONArray getBoothList(String data) {
    JSONArray assemblyArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {

        jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        String PolingStation = (String) jsonObj.get("PolingStation");
        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        ResultSet boothList = con
                .query("SELECT booth_id,booth_name,booth_status FROM tbl_booth where polingstation_id = "
                        + PolingStation + ";");

        while (boothList.next()) {
            JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
            jO.put("booth_id", boothList.getInt(1));
            jO.put("booth_name", boothList.getString(2));
            jO.put("booth_status", boothList.getInt(3));
            assemblyArray.put(jO);
        }

        if (assemblyArray != null) {
            return assemblyArray;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }

    return new JSONArray();
}

public String CreateColony(String data) {
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        String AssemblyID = (String) jsonObj.get("AssemblyID");
        String PolingStationID = (String) jsonObj.get("PolingStationID");
        String boothID = (String) jsonObj.get("BoothID");
        String Colonyname = (String) jsonObj.get("Colonyname");

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        int i = con
                .insertAndgeneratedRowId("INSERT INTO `tbl_colony` (`colony_name`) VALUES ('" + Colonyname + "');");

        if (i > 0) {

            int j = con.insertAndgeneratedRowId("INSERT INTO `txn_booth_colony` (`booth_id`, `colony_id`) VALUES ('"
                    + boothID + "', '" + i + "');");
            if (j > 0)
                return "success";
            else
                return "Failure";

        } else {

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return null;
}

public JSONArray getColonyList(String data) {

    JSONArray assemblyArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {

        jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        String boothID = (String) jsonObj.get("boothID");
        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        ResultSet boothList = con
                .query("SELECT colony_id , colony_name FROM tbl_colony where colony_id in (SELECT colony_id FROM txn_booth_colony where booth_id = "
                        + boothID + ")");

        while (boothList.next()) {
            JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
            jO.put("colony_id", boothList.getInt(1));
            jO.put("colony_name", boothList.getString(2));

            assemblyArray.put(jO);
        }

        if (assemblyArray != null) {
            return assemblyArray;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage()); 
    }

    return new JSONArray();

}

public JSONArray getLoginAssembly() {
    JSONArray assemblyArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        ResultSet assemblyList = con
                .query("SELECT assembly_id, assembly_name FROM tbl_assembly  where assembly_status = 1 ;");

        while (assemblyList.next()) {
            JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
            jO.put("AssemblyID", assemblyList.getInt(1));
            jO.put("AssemblyName", assemblyList.getString(2));

            assemblyArray.put(jO);
        }

        if (assemblyArray != null) {
            return assemblyArray;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new JSONArray();
}

public void getGenerateOTP(String assembly, String userid) {

    try {
        properties = commonUtil.getProperty();

        URL obj = new URL(properties.getProperty(VplEndPoints.SendOTP.URL));

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String POST_PARAMS = "AssemblyID=" + assembly + "&UserID=" + userid;
        System.out.println(POST_PARAMS);
        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result

        } else {
            logger.info("POST request not worked");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public LoginPojo validateWithPassword(String assembly, String userid, String password) {

    LoginPojo LoginPojo = new LoginPojo();
    try {
        properties = commonUtil.getProperty();

        URL obj = new URL(properties.getProperty(VplEndPoints.LoginWithPassword.URL));

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String POST_PARAMS = "AssemblyID=" + assembly + "&UserID=" + userid + "&Password=" + password;
        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            LoginPojo = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), LoginPojo.class);

            return LoginPojo;

        } else {
            logger.info("POST request not worked");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean loginWithOTP(String assembly, String userid, String otp)  {

    LoginPojo LoginPojo = new LoginPojo();
    try {
        properties = commonUtil.getProperty();

        URL obj = new URL(properties.getProperty(VplEndPoints.LoginWithOTP.URL));

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String POST_PARAMS = "AssemblyID=" + assembly + "&UserID=" + userid + "&OTP=" + otp;
        System.out.println(POST_PARAMS);
        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            LoginPojo = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), LoginPojo.class);

            if (LoginPojo.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            logger.info("POST request not worked");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean validateWithPassword_SU(String userid, String password) {
    LoginPojo LoginPojo = new LoginPojo();
    try {
        properties = commonUtil.getProperty();

        URL obj = new URL(properties.getProperty(VplEndPoints.SuperUserLoginWithPassword.URL));

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String POST_PARAMS = "UserID=" + userid + "&Password=" + password;
        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            LoginPojo = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), LoginPojo.class);

            if (LoginPojo.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            logger.info("POST request not worked");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean loginWithOTP_SU(String userid, String otp) {

    LoginPojo LoginPojo = new LoginPojo();
    try {
        properties = commonUtil.getProperty();

        URL obj = new URL(properties.getProperty(VplEndPoints.SuperUserLoginWithOTP.URL));

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String POST_PARAMS = "UserID=" + userid + "&OTP=" + otp;
        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            LoginPojo = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), LoginPojo.class);

            if (LoginPojo.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            logger.info("POST request not worked");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

public void getGenerateOTP_SU(String userid) {
    try {
        properties = commonUtil.getProperty();

        URL obj = new URL(properties.getProperty(VplEndPoints.SuperUserSendOTP.URL));

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String POST_PARAMS = "UserID=" + userid;
        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result

        } else {
            logger.info("POST request not worked");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void setAllDeactivate(int boothID, int colonyID) {
    try {

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        int i = con.insert("UPDATE `tbl_voter` SET `voter_status`='0' WHERE colony_id = " + colonyID
                + " and booth_id = " + boothID + ";");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public boolean isExist(String voterId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();

        ResultSet voterIdRS = con.query("SELECT voter_id FROM tbl_voter where voter_uid = '" + voterId + "'");

        while (voterIdRS.next()) {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

public void updateExisting(String voterId, String name, String cname, int houseNo, int age, String gender) {
    try {

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();
        String gend = "";
        if (gender == "male") {
            gend = "M";
        } else {
            gend = "F";
        }
        int UE = con.insert("UPDATE `tbl_voter` SET `voter_name`='" + name + "', `gender`='" + gend
                + "', `care_of_name`='" + cname + "', `age`=" + age + ", `plot_no`=" + houseNo
                + ", `voter_status`='1' WHERE voter_uid = '" + voterId + "';");

        if (UE > 0) {

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void insertNew(String voterId, String name, String cname, int houseNo, int age, String gender) {
    try {

        MySqlConnect con = MySqlConnect.getDbCon();
        String gend = "";
        if (gender == "male") {
            gend = "M";
        } else {
            gend = "F";
        }
        int UE = con
                .insert("INSERT INTO `tbl_voter` (`voter_name`, `voter_uid`, `gender`, `care_of_name`, `age`, `plot_no`, `colony_id`, `booth_id`, `current_status`, `caste_id`, `is_voted`, `is_voter_parchi_send`, `question_id`, `option_id`, `voter_status`)"
                        + " VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + voterId + "', '" + gend + "', '" + cname + "', " + age
                        + ", " + houseNo + ", '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1');");

        if (UE > 0) {

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the  `AdminServiceImpl`?

Comment: updated @Aris_Kortex

Comment: Exceptions are logged as "info". You might want to log them as errors, because infos are typically not displayed (without knowing your actual logging configuration). Then you'd be able to see the root cause yourself and might be able to fix it yourself (or add the information to this question)

Comment: ...and, unrelated to your question, but very much related to the code that you show: Read about prepared SQL statements, SQL-injection vulnerabilities and [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/), then make it a priority to fix the sql statements in your inherited application. All of them.

Comment: @HariPrasadJha, your question is related to MySQL so I added that tag and removed the sql-server tag, which is for Microsoft SQL Server, a different DBMS.

Comment: Did you run the code in a debugger (such as Eclipse or IntelliJ) to see where the problem is occurring?  Learning how to remote debug Tomcat in your favorite IDE is tremendous time-saver for this and all future problems.

Comment: @HariPrasadJha *Welcome to [so]!* Please take a moment to read how to create a [mcve].